# What is the purpose of the Manage Display in Content type?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-views

For example, in the Body field there is a **LABEL** with the following values:
[image]

And there is **FORMAT** with such values:

[image]

How does something change on the site depending on the selected values in the Manage Display and what does each value mean?
I tried to create my Content and change these values in Manage Display. But nothing happens to my Content and it doesn’t change at all. Although I tried to choose different view mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does something change on the site depending on the selected values in the Manage Display and what does each value mean?

**Manage display** manages the way your content is displayed on the frontend. Generally speaking how visitors will see your site's content. There are however more purposes for displays and separate view modes, but this is its simplest usage.

- The "Label" display options relate to the "Field" name. In your screenshot the default options show how you can change how the **Body** field label would be displayed or even be hidden from display.
- The "Format" display options allow for display control on the content for the field in question. Ie. to show the full body, trimmed or summary.

> I tried to create my Content and change these values in Manage Display. But nothing happens to my Content and it doesn’t change at all. Although I tried to choose different view mode.

Most likely you may either be changing the display options from the wrong view mode or your content rendering is not running through the usual preprocess function / templates. I would look into your theme folder and find anything unusual relevant to the content type or fields.